# Implement photo collage

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, shapes

I'm working on a collage maker app, the board is having 4 layouts `RelativeLayout`, the layouts contains `ImageView`s in them and the imageViews are applies to *drag*, *move* and *zoom*.
All of the layouts could be a custom shape like *triangle* or *diagonal lines* like in pictures.

[image: triangles]

[image: diagonal]

I have tried to use a custom `RelativeLayout` and added Override for `dispatchDraw`, using `clipPath` to make a custom shape.

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2
            && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
        Path clipPath = new Path();
        clipPath.addPath(triangle());
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}

public Path triangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3)
{
    Path p = new Path();
    float midX = getWidth() / 2;
    float midY = getHeight() / 2;

    p.moveTo(midX, midY);
    p.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    p.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
    p.lineTo(p3.x, p3.y);
    p.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    retrun p;
}
```

The `clipPath` somehow do a part of the trick, but it draw the path and make the out parts transparent but didn't cut them so the layout still rectangle and not triangle.

I want something that make the layout be as exactly the path shape.

any solution?

Comment: Nice, you have a full code ? I can help you :)

Comment: have you solve this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't find a solution for this.